# How does template function work with multiple typenames which may share an intersection?

Tags: c++, templates, generic-programming

I am new to C++ and currently trying to understand how template functions work. First I wanted to add two numerical values of the same type, which is quite easy to understand.

```
template <typename T>
T add(T a, T b){return a+b;}
int main(){
    float a_f=2.5;float b_f=1.5;float c_f;
    int a_i=2;int b_i=1;int c_i;
    c_f = add(a_f, b_f);
    c_i = add(a_i, b_i);
    return 0;
}
```

Next I wanted to add two numerical numbers with different and equal types. My naive assumption was this:

```
template<typename R, typename S, typename T>
R add(S a, T b){return a+b;}
int main(){
    float a=3.2; int b=2;
    auto result1 = add(a,b);    // error: no matching function for call to ‘add(float&, int&)’
    auto result2 = add(a,a);    // error: no matching function for call to ‘add(float&, float&)’
    auto result3 = add(b,b);    // error: no matching function for call to ‘add(int&, int&)’
    return 0;
}
```

I am aware that this approach is not correct, because the typename's share an intersection regarding data types and therefore the declaration itself cannot be correct.

How could a simple add() function be implemented that adds two numeric values together, regardless of type?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is not with an intersection, but that it cant deduce `R`.  In

```
template<typename R, typename S, typename T>
R add(S a, T b){return a+b;}
```

There is nothing telling the compiler what `R` should be.  It's not deduced from the variable you are assigning the result to and you do not specify it, so there is no valid call that it can do.  To fix this you can just get rid of `R` and use the `auto` return type to have it deduced for you like

```
template<typename S, typename T>
auto add(S a, T b){return a+b;}
```

Answer (score 5):

> How could a simple `add()` function be implemented that adds two numeric values together, regardless of type?

In C++14:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

In the above, the type of the return value is deduced from the type of expression `t + u`.

C++11 doesn't deduce return types but allows for trailing return type, so a C++11 version is:

```
template<class T, class U>
auto add(T t, U u) -> decltype(t + u) {
    return t + u;
}
```

Comment: Aha this makes sense and solved my problem. Could you explain why you are using 'class' instead of 'typename'.

Comment: @One3Three7 `class` is shorter to type and there is no difference in this context between `class` and `typename`.

Comment: You can add `-> decltype(t + u)` before `{` for C++11 compatibility.

Comment: ... or `-> std::common_type<S,T>::type`

Comment: @MSalters That is so C++98, if only it had `std::common_type`.

Comment: @One3Three7 I prefer `typename` and would like others to write this way because it's a better expression of one's intention. Readability is important.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: Or trailing return types.

Comment: @passing_through That's your preference but it carries no added benefit.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin ...except for a small increase in readability.

Comment: @passing_through To prove that you'd need to conduct a study. I see unnecessary clutter, not increased readability. Clutter reduces readability. I can read both ways, but can only write `class`.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is to deduce the return type. However, type deduction for type template parameter only apply for function parameter.

Even though typenames are not the right tool to do that, C++ offers other mean to deduce the type.

### Use auto

You can simply put `auto` there and let the compiler deduce from the return type:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
auto add(S a, T b){ return a + b; }
```

### Use trailing return types

You can also use the trailing return type if you want to be more explicit on the return type of the function:

```
template<typename S, typename T>
auto add(S a, T b) -> decltype(a + b) { return a + b; }
```